# StackDump - offline browser for Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion

Well, I was searching for the offline version of the Stack Exchange website and got to a term called StackDump. I don't have huge disk space as it requires 70-80 GB disk space and 3 GB of RAM. I'm interested in [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29) and the knowledge here is freaking awesome. So, can anybody guide me how to achieve this scenario?

Comment: What are you trying to ask?

Comment: steps to configure offline version of this site..

Comment: Why would you want an offline version of this site?

Comment: as i mentioned for the knowledge purpose..

Comment: Why not simply stay online and visit the site?

Comment: Note that the dump is not an offline version of the entire site experience anyway - it's just the raw data.

Comment: @TT The obvious answer there is not being able to stay online.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The dump can be downloaded from [The Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange).

However if you're unable to use it due to disk space and/or knowledge limitations, stick to the online site.