# Stack Overflow separated cumulative dump for the Python tag

Tags: discussion

I'm interested in an offline version of Stack Overflow where I can read/study on the run as my job is an interstate courier that does not always have an Internet connection. Using 3G data is very expensive though.

Is there a way to download an offline dump from Stack Overflow for a specific programming language tag? For example, I'm learning Python. Downloading the whole site seems not reasonable as it is too big and not necessary.

How do I browse it alike the "outlook" style, for example, the title column and content panel?

Comment: Related: *[StackDump - offline browser for Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314125)*